# Why does mongodb aggreate $unwind change my $sort order?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb (4.2) aggregate function like this:

```
Wine.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$match": {
                "user": ObjectId("<userId>"),
                "deleted": false,
                "$or": [
                    {
                        "mode": "past"
                    },
                    {
                        "mode": "group"
                    },
                    {
                        "$and": [
                            {
                                "mode":"event"
                            },
                            {
                                "sameAs": {
                                    "$exists": true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "created": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "wineuniversals", // the collection name
                "localField": "wineUniversal", // field from the wines model
                "foreignField": "_id", // field how the two collections are linked
                "as": "uWineData" // the object property where the universal wine data is stored
            }
        },
        {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$uWineData"
            }
        }
    ]
).exec(function(err, wines) {...});
```

Example output without $unwind: (5 docs returned)

```
[{"_id":"5ed5b3d186bff9019b43d173","scoreAroma":4.5,"scoreTaste":4.5,"scoreFinish":4.3,"scoreOverallImpression":4.4,"scoreTotal":94.3,"comment":"Amazingly delicious!","groupDescription":"none","quantity":1,"eventBlindTasting":false,"deleted":false,"hidden":false,"wineUniversal":null,"created":"2020-06-05T03:18:09.428Z","mode":"past","lastUpdated":"2020-06-05T03:18:09.428Z","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","photoURL":"00d28cb99a8460816e0c079cea8f9f45","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Powerful"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Apple","Pear","Pitted Fruit","Tropical"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Baked","Ripe"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["None"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Complex"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Off Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Low"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Full"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Tropical"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Tart","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Floral","Vegetal"]}},"visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["Some"]},"Color":{"values":["Straw"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Pale"]}},"uWineData":[]},{"_id":"5ed081414df3ac537644e827","scoreAroma":4,"scoreTaste":4.4,"scoreFinish":4.2,"scoreOverallImpression":4.2,"scoreTotal":92.3,"comment":"comment: none","groupDescription":"2017 Domaine Jean Royer, Chateauneuf du Pape","quantity":1,"eventBlindTasting":false,"deleted":false,"hidden":false,"wineUniversal":null,"created":"2020-05-27T20:48:49.149Z","eventLink":"5ecec8b7e3b963049276ecfc","mode":"event","eventListOrder":0,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-29T03:28:50.506Z","photoURL":"fd7f45af94457ec9e575f62fe1fc32b0","__v":0,"sameAs":"5eced200e3b963049276ed05","visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Lot"]},"Color":{"values":["Garnet"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Deep"]}},"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Delicate"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Black Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Ripe","Fresh","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Licorice","Honey"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Fresh Soil"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["Low"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Full"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Red Fruit","Black Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Ripe"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Spice","Licorice","Tobacco"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Forest Floor","Fresh Soil"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Complex"]}},"user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","uWineData":[]},{"_id":"5dbbc408e78d867664213147","photoURL":"51972ee99dec8f31cdb6ff8025a0d3d3","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dce6038e78d8676642131fd","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"Surprisingly tasty. You'd think it's be olonk based on the gimmicky label.","scoreTotal":91,"scoreOverallImpression":4.2,"scoreFinish":4,"scoreTaste":4,"scoreAroma":4.3,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-21T23:06:54.497Z","created":"2020-05-21T23:06:54.498Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Powerful"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit","Black Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Ripe","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Wood","Tobacco"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["Low"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Medium"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Red Fruit","Black Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Fresh","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Spice","Wood","Tobacco"]}},"visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Dull"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["Some"]},"Color":{"values":["Garnet"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Deep"]}},"uWineData":[{"_id":"5dce6038e78d8676642131fd","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":0,"userWines":["5dbbc408e78d867664213147"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":null,"expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":null,"currency":"USD","commonPrice":12,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"","category":"Red","varietal":"Cabernet Sauvignon","vineyard":"","appellation":"California","subRegion":"","region":"California","country":"United States","wineryUrl":"https://www.thewalkingdeadwine.com","winery":"The Walking Dead Wines","vintage":"2016","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-11-15T08:22:32.437Z","created":"2019-11-15T08:22:16.579Z","__v":1}]},{"_id":"5dbe0233e78d86766421317b","photoURL":"64132a46cceddb94d223dafcd38dc572","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dce97cfe78d867664213236","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"This wine has been great with every vintage I've tried. Balanced, complex, delicious red fruit bright acidity with enough fruit to balance it out. Light tannins and just a touch of oaky spice. Wonderful!!","scoreTotal":93.7,"scoreOverallImpression":4.4,"scoreFinish":4.2,"scoreTaste":4.4,"scoreAroma":4.5,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-19T23:58:47.219Z","created":"2020-05-19T23:58:47.220Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Powerful"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Spice","Wood"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["Low"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Full"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Tart","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Spice","Licorice","Wood"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone"]}},"visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Few"]},"Color":{"values":["Ruby"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Medium"]}},"uWineData":[{"_id":"5dce97cfe78d867664213236","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":95.1,"userWines":["5dbe0233e78d86766421317b","5dfea3bde78d8676642135f4"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":"none","expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":"none","currency":"USD","commonPrice":14,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"Firehouse Red","category":"Red","varietal":"Red Blend","vineyard":"","appellation":"Columbia Valley","subRegion":"Columbia Valley","region":"Washington","country":"United States","wineryUrl":"http://www.tamarackcellars.com","winery":"Tamarack cellars","vintage":"2016","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-12-21T23:15:06.578Z","created":"2019-11-15T12:19:27.348Z","__v":2}]},{"_id":"5df533bee78d8676642134d4","photoURL":"077d87cb7aac91cc59f3a0cf1f981197","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dfb322fe78d867664213582","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"Moderately big wine. Heavy acidity, tartness, and with a great red and blue fruit aromas.","scoreTotal":90.9,"scoreOverallImpression":4.1,"scoreFinish":3.9,"scoreTaste":4.1,"scoreAroma":4.3,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-14T22:31:13.806Z","created":"2020-05-14T22:31:13.807Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit","Blue Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Ripe","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Floral","Herbal","Spice"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["None"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["No"]},"Balance: If No, Which of the Following Elements Stick Out?":{"values":["Acidity","Tannin"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Full"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Red Fruit","Blue Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Tart","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Wood"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone","Petrol"]}},"visualTags":{"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Few"]},"Color":{"values":["Ruby"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Deep"]}},"uWineData":[{"_id":"5dfb322fe78d867664213582","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":0,"userWines":["5df533bee78d8676642134d4"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":null,"expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":null,"currency":"USD","commonPrice":30,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"","category":"Red","varietal":"Red Bordeaux Blend","vineyard":"","appellation":"Saint-Emilion Grand Cru","subRegion":"Saint-Emilion","region":"Bordeaux","country":"France","wineryUrl":"","winery":"Chateau Patris Querre","vintage":"2016","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-12-19T08:18:00.075Z","created":"2019-12-19T08:17:51.237Z","__v":1}]}]
```

And here's example output with the $unwind step added to my aggregate pipeline: (5 docs returned)

```
[{"_id":"5dbbc408e78d867664213147","photoURL":"51972ee99dec8f31cdb6ff8025a0d3d3","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dce6038e78d8676642131fd","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"Surprisingly tasty. You'd think it's be olonk based on the gimmicky label.","scoreTotal":91,"scoreOverallImpression":4.2,"scoreFinish":4,"scoreTaste":4,"scoreAroma":4.3,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-21T23:06:54.497Z","created":"2020-05-21T23:06:54.498Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Powerful"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit","Black Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Ripe","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Wood","Tobacco"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["Low"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Medium"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Red Fruit","Black Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Fresh","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Spice","Wood","Tobacco"]}},"visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Dull"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["Some"]},"Color":{"values":["Garnet"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Deep"]}},"uWineData":{"_id":"5dce6038e78d8676642131fd","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":0,"userWines":["5dbbc408e78d867664213147"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":null,"expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":null,"currency":"USD","commonPrice":12,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"","category":"Red","varietal":"Cabernet Sauvignon","vineyard":"","appellation":"California","subRegion":"","region":"California","country":"United States","wineryUrl":"https://www.thewalkingdeadwine.com","winery":"The Walking Dead Wines","vintage":"2016","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-11-15T08:22:32.437Z","created":"2019-11-15T08:22:16.579Z","__v":1}},{"_id":"5dbe0233e78d86766421317b","photoURL":"64132a46cceddb94d223dafcd38dc572","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dce97cfe78d867664213236","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"This wine has been great with every vintage I've tried. Balanced, complex, delicious red fruit bright acidity with enough fruit to balance it out. Light tannins and just a touch of oaky spice. Wonderful!!","scoreTotal":93.7,"scoreOverallImpression":4.4,"scoreFinish":4.2,"scoreTaste":4.4,"scoreAroma":4.5,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-19T23:58:47.219Z","created":"2020-05-19T23:58:47.220Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Powerful"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Spice","Wood"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["Low"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Full"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Tart","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Spice","Licorice","Wood"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone"]}},"visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Few"]},"Color":{"values":["Ruby"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Medium"]}},"uWineData":{"_id":"5dce97cfe78d867664213236","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":95.1,"userWines":["5dbe0233e78d86766421317b","5dfea3bde78d8676642135f4"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":"none","expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":"none","currency":"USD","commonPrice":14,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"Firehouse Red","category":"Red","varietal":"Red Blend","vineyard":"","appellation":"Columbia Valley","subRegion":"Columbia Valley","region":"Washington","country":"United States","wineryUrl":"http://www.tamarackcellars.com","winery":"Tamarack cellars","vintage":"2016","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-12-21T23:15:06.578Z","created":"2019-11-15T12:19:27.348Z","__v":2}},{"_id":"5df533bee78d8676642134d4","photoURL":"077d87cb7aac91cc59f3a0cf1f981197","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dfb322fe78d867664213582","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"Moderately big wine. Heavy acidity, tartness, and with a great red and blue fruit aromas.","scoreTotal":90.9,"scoreOverallImpression":4.1,"scoreFinish":3.9,"scoreTaste":4.1,"scoreAroma":4.3,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-14T22:31:13.806Z","created":"2020-05-14T22:31:13.807Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit","Blue Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Ripe","Jammy"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Floral","Herbal","Spice"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["None"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium Long"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["No"]},"Balance: If No, Which of the Following Elements Stick Out?":{"values":["Acidity","Tannin"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Full"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Red Fruit","Blue Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Tart","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Wood"]},"Organic/Inorganic":{"values":["Stone","Petrol"]}},"visualTags":{"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Few"]},"Color":{"values":["Ruby"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Deep"]}},"uWineData":{"_id":"5dfb322fe78d867664213582","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":0,"userWines":["5df533bee78d8676642134d4"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":null,"expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":null,"currency":"USD","commonPrice":30,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"","category":"Red","varietal":"Red Bordeaux Blend","vineyard":"","appellation":"Saint-Emilion Grand Cru","subRegion":"Saint-Emilion","region":"Bordeaux","country":"France","wineryUrl":"","winery":"Chateau Patris Querre","vintage":"2016","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-12-19T08:18:00.075Z","created":"2019-12-19T08:17:51.237Z","__v":1}},{"_id":"5df53385e78d8676642134d3","photoURL":"a7beda1ac343ff8d7fffccd32208db84","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dfb3795e78d86766421358d","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"Earthy cherry with a light ashy finish.","scoreTotal":91.5,"scoreOverallImpression":4.2,"scoreFinish":4,"scoreTaste":4.2,"scoreAroma":4.2,"lastUpdated":"2020-05-06T00:01:34.559Z","created":"2020-05-05T23:20:15.043Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Intensity":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Tart","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal"]},"Oak Intensity":{"values":["None"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium"]}},"overallTags":{"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["Yes"]},"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]}},"tasteTags":{"Sweetness":{"values":["Off Dry"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Medium"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Tart","Ripe","Fresh"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Spice","Licorice"]}},"visualTags":{"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Lot"]},"Color":{"values":["Ruby"]},"Color Intensity":{"values":["Pale"]}},"uWineData":{"_id":"5dfb3795e78d86766421358d","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":0,"userWines":["5df53385e78d8676642134d3"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":null,"expertScore1":"90","expertReviewer1":"WE","currency":"USD","commonPrice":39,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"Barrel Select","category":"Red","varietal":"Pinot Noir","vineyard":"","appellation":"Willamette Valley","subRegion":"Willamette","region":"Oregon","country":"United States","wineryUrl":"https://www.wvv.com","winery":"Willamette Valley Vineyards","vintage":"2017","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-12-19T08:41:08.067Z","created":"2019-12-19T08:40:53.913Z","__v":1}},{"_id":"5df533d2e78d8676642134d5","photoURL":"4d6d4c42bc5218d64fb134f4a8eb9f5f","user":"554f99352ee62248071b4d0f","mode":"past","wineUniversal":"5dfb3158e78d86766421357f","hidden":false,"deleted":false,"eventBlindTasting":false,"quantity":1,"groupDescription":"none","comment":"","scoreTotal":89.3,"scoreOverallImpression":3.9,"scoreFinish":3.8,"scoreTaste":4,"scoreAroma":4,"lastUpdated":"2020-03-18T23:09:30.869Z","created":"2020-03-18T23:09:30.869Z","__v":0,"aromaTags":{"Oak Intensity":{"values":["None"]},"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Floral","Herbal"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Tart","Fresh"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Citrus","Red Fruit"]}},"finishTags":{"Length/Finish":{"values":["Medium"]}},"overallTags":{"Complexity":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Balance: If No, Which of the Following Elements Stick Out?":{"values":["Acidity"]},"Is the Wine Balanced?":{"values":["No"]}},"tasteTags":{"Non-Fruit":{"values":["Herbal","Spice","Wood"]},"Fruit Character":{"values":["Peel/Skin","Tart","Fresh"]},"Fruit":{"values":["Red Fruit"]},"Body/Texture":{"values":["Medium"]},"Alcohol":{"values":["Moderate"]},"Acid":{"values":["Moderately High"]},"Tannins":{"values":["Moderately Low"]},"Sweetness":{"values":["Dry"]}},"visualTags":{"Color Intensity":{"values":["Medium"]},"Color":{"values":["Ruby"]},"Legs on the side of the glass (Viscosity/Tears)":{"values":["A Lot"]},"Sediment or Particles":{"values":["No"]},"Brightness":{"values":["Bright"]},"Clarity":{"values":["Clear"]}},"uWineData":{"_id":"5dfb3158e78d86766421357f","scoreCount":1,"averageScore":0,"userWines":["5df533d2e78d8676642134d5"],"expertScore2":"","expertReviewer2":null,"expertScore1":"","expertReviewer1":null,"currency":"USD","commonPrice":42,"additionalDetails":"","designation":"Stanley Groovy","category":"Red","varietal":"Red Blend","vineyard":"","appellation":"Red Mountain","subRegion":"Columbia Valley","region":"Washington","country":"United States","wineryUrl":"https://www.thewallsvineyards.com","winery":"The Walls Vineyards","vintage":"2017","deleted":false,"lastUpdated":"2019-12-19T08:14:22.142Z","created":"2019-12-19T08:14:16.093Z","__v":1}}]
```

Here is one doc without $unwind:

```
{
    "_id": "5ed5b3d186bff9019b43d173",
    "scoreAroma": 4.5,
    "scoreTaste": 4.5,
    "scoreFinish": 4.3,
    "scoreOverallImpression": 4.4,
    "scoreTotal": 94.3,
    "comment": "Amazingly delicious!",
    "groupDescription": "none",
    "quantity": 1,
    "eventBlindTasting": false,
    "deleted": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "wineUniversal": null,
    "created": "2020-06-05T03:18:09.428Z",
    "mode": "past",
    "lastUpdated": "2020-06-05T03:18:09.428Z",
    "user": "554f99352ee62248071b4d0f",
    "photoURL": "00d28cb99a8460816e0c079cea8f9f45",
    "uWineData": []
}
```

And here is a doc with the $unwind step added:

```
{
    "_id": "5dbbc408e78d867664213147",
    "photoURL": "51972ee99dec8f31cdb6ff8025a0d3d3",
    "user": "554f99352ee62248071b4d0f",
    "mode": "past",
    "wineUniversal": "5dce6038e78d8676642131fd",
    "hidden": false,
    "deleted": false,
    "eventBlindTasting": false,
    "quantity": 1,
    "groupDescription": "none",
    "comment": "Surprisingly tasty. You'd think it's be olonk based on the gimmicky label.",
    "scoreTotal": 91,
    "scoreOverallImpression": 4.2,
    "scoreFinish": 4,
    "scoreTaste": 4,
    "scoreAroma": 4.3,
    "lastUpdated": "2020-05-21T23:06:54.497Z",
    "created": "2020-05-21T23:06:54.498Z",
    "uWineData": {
        "_id": "5dce6038e78d8676642131fd",
        "scoreCount": 1,
        "averageScore": 0,
        "userWines": ["5dbbc408e78d867664213147"],
        "expertScore2": "",
        "expertReviewer2": null,
        "expertScore1": "",
        "expertReviewer1": null,
        "currency": "USD",
        "commonPrice": 12,
        "additionalDetails": "",
        "designation": "",
        "category": "Red",
        "varietal": "Cabernet Sauvignon",
        "vineyard": "",
        "appellation": "California",
        "subRegion": "",
        "region": "California",
        "country": "United States",
        "wineryUrl": "https://www.thewalkingdeadwine.com",
        "winery": "The Walking Dead Wines",
        "vintage": "2016",
        "deleted": false,
        "lastUpdated": "2019-11-15T08:22:32.437Z",
        "created": "2019-11-15T08:22:16.579Z",
        "__v": 1
    }
}
```

If i run the aggregate call without the $unwind step in my pipeline the sort order is correct. But as soon as I add in the $unwind step, my sort order gives me differently ordered results. Why is this?

POSSIBLE PROBLEM:
Is the problem something to do with there being two `created` properties in the doc after the $unwind step is called? If that causes the problem, how do I target the top level `created` fied?

Comment: Can we see some sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Could this be something to do with that there is a `created` property in the `wineuniversals` model too and that the $sort is keying off of that `created` property instead of the `created` in the parent doc?

Comment: The output with unwind is sorted according to your criteria.

Comment: So how do I target the other `created` field instead of the $unwind'ed `created` field?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue of for the most recent top-level docs there wasn't yet a sub-doc linked to it. I added the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true` property to my $unwind step and now the sort is behaving as expected.

```
{
    "path": "$uWineData",
    "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
}
```